# Looking for a tool to view/manage Database created by JPA

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I am developing an application with play framework and JPA/Hibernate for the database. I reached a stage that I need to see how the database looks like to check my code correctness. I have tried CRUD module but it's very limited. I need a tool that I can use to see and navigate the database created under the hood by JPA. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you check [squirrel](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 2):

Try the new database view in Play 1.2 http://localhost:9000/@db
Simple but useful ;)

Answer (score 1):

I like [Db Visualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) which has a free community edition and it has a feature that creates diagrams of tables associated with the one you have currently selected in the tree view. I use it to analyze how Hibernate creates tables for me during the design/JPA annotation phase. This is the best tool I have used for this work.

If you can pay some money, I really like [Aqua Data Studio](http://www.aquafold.com/), it has a diagram generation feature that is pretty cool.

If you are using MySQL then you may consider [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) it also has a feature to generate diagrams out of your current tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Oracle DB or MySQL, your best option is [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html), one of best in its kind.

To get mysql connectivity, you need to select Preferences/Extensions and check update on 3rd party extensions: you will see the MySQL driver show up.